# How to set action for back icon in navigation drawer in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am a newbie in android and I have problem when I made my application with material design. I follow [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/) tutorial and create a fragment that allow searching tickets as this picuture [image]. 
After search button is clicked, fragment Result will be display such as this [image].

But I don't know how I can set action for back icon in toolbar to back previous fragment. When I draw back icon, it always show navigation drawer and i just can back previous fragment when I touch back icon on my devices, but when i do that, the title of toolbar not changing. For example, when I am in fragment resutl, if i click back on devices i will back to Searching fragment, but the tittle of toolbar is title of Result. please help me. 
p/s: So sorry if this question is stupid, but I stuck with it more three day. I also search in Google and stackoverflow, but maybe I'm not fully understand about navigation drawer so I try but can not resolved. I'm also sorry if i wrong grammar because my english is not good and thanks you for reading my question
Here is my code to replace fragement searching ticket into Result.

```
 public  void DataBundle(ArrayList<TicketInforModel> ticketInforModels){
        ResultFragment rFrag = new ResultFragment();
        Bundle packageDataStation = new Bundle();
        packageDataStation.putSerializable("arrTicket",ticketInforModels);
;
        rFrag.setArguments(packageDataStation);
        //noinspection ResourceType
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, rFrag);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        // set the toolbar title
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);//get Toolbar from SearchingTicketActivity
        ((SearchingTicketActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ((SearchingTicketActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_result);

       toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_back);

       // toolbar.dismissPopupMenus();
    }
```

Comment: See the edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           getSupportFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I also tried it, but it's not working for me. Are you vietnamese ?

Comment: Yes, I'm Vietnamese. You want to change title of toolbar when press back ?. In onCreateView() function of Fragment, try to implement getActivity().setTitle("Namse Fragment") function

Comment: I'm Vietnamese too lol. Thanks for answer, but getActivity().setTitle("Namse Fragment") is not working. It still keep title of old fragment when click back icon. And how i can disable or dismiss menu ?. when i draw in fragment, menu always display.

Comment: You mean menu in the top right of screen or where ?

Comment: top left, when touch in menu icon in toolbar, and getSupportFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(); just only previous one fragment. when i try searching -> Result -> Booking and i click back icon Booking -> result it works perfect, but i try Booking -> Result -> serching it show null pointer exception.

Comment: Please post your logcat when error null pointer exception appear

Comment: do you have teamview or facebook?

Comment: LOL, just post here, you will receive help from many people, this will help you learn faster. Believe me :D

Answer (score 1):

Listen for click events on `android.R.id.home` like usual:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
            case android.R.id.home:
            //Do your stuff
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

**Note :** In such circumstances it's good practice to show the result in new `Activity` when you pressing the search button and you can get back after `finish()` the result activity by pressing `home/up` button in the `toolbar`.Don't make it so complicated.

Comment: I have tried it before, but it's not working for me.

Comment: thanks for your advices, I will do it for next application. Because i want try using fragment so I do my application such as tutorial :(